# Pushing Cookie Value Data to Hidden Fields

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, marketo

I recently installed a script that creates a Google __utmz cookie for my site visitors, and it sets all of the fields. Below is a look at it.

```html
<script>
function get_campaign_info()
{
 var utma = get_utm_value(document.cookie, '__utma=', ';');
 var utmb = get_utm_value(document.cookie, '__utmb=', ';');
 var utmc = get_utm_value(document.cookie, '__utmc=', ';');
 var utmz = get_utm_value(document.cookie, '__utmz=', ';');
 
 source = get_utm_value(utmz, 'utmcsr=', '|');
 medium = get_utm_value(utmz, 'utmcmd=', '|');
 term = get_utm_value(utmz, 'utmctr=', '|');
 content = get_utm_value(utmz, 'utmcct=', '|');
 campaign = get_utm_value(utmz, 'utmccn=', '|');
 gclid = get_utm_value(utmz, 'utmgclid=', '|');
 
 session_count = get_session_count(utma);
 pageview_count = get_pageview_count(utmb, utmc);
  
 if (gclid !="-") {
  source = 'google';
  medium = 'cpc';
 }
}

</script>
```

Looking through my cookies I can see that it is being created. For example heres a bit of it: 
"47664550.1486736628.2.2.utmcsr=website.com|utmccn=(referral)"

I have another script which is cleaning it all up and posting it to my console. [image: A look at my console]

The issue that I am finding is that I can't figure out how to push those fields, like Campaign Medium, to hidden form fields on my site. Below is a look at how my typical Marketo form creates hidden fields with user data.

```html
MktoForms2.whenReady(function(form){   
  ga(function(){   
    form.addHiddenFields({   
      GA_User_ID__c : ga.getByName('gtm1').get('userId')
     
  });  
});
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can push medium, session, etc. to hidden fields? Thanks for any advice or just for reading! If it helps, the page I've been running tests on is powerreviews.com/form-test

Comment: You're setting global variables in the `get_campaign_info()` function, so you should be able to use those global variables when creating the hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

For Marketo forms you should use the Marketo Form API. Go to [this page](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/assets/forms/examples/) and scroll down to the hidden field example.

In case the URL changes, here is the example code:

```
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjst.marketo.com", "785-UHP-775", 1057, function (form) { 
    // Set values for the hidden fields, "userIsAwesome" and "enrollDate"
    // Note that these fields were configured in the form editor as hidden fields already
    form.vals({"userIsAwesome":"true", "enrollDate":"2014-01-01"});
});
```